# regular expression for checking a tv show

Tags: c#, regex

im looking for a regular expression that checks or it is an tv show or just a movie by searching for by example `S01E01` in `"24.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-FoV.avi"`

so i

```
bool check = Regex.IsMatch(filename, "^(*[a-z][A-Z][0-9].){*}S\\d\\dE\\d\\d(*[a-z][A-Z][0-9].){*}")
```

but it doesn't look like visual studio is very happy with that...
does anywone has a sugestion?

Comment: Well this looks very legal...

Comment: Why does it matter if *Visual Studio* is "happy" with your Regex?

Comment: i mean that it doesn't work...

Comment: It definitely needs some work.  If you want to match a period you have to escape it.  Asterisks that mean zero or more are postfix, not prefix operators.  And as a suggestion, use verbatim strings....

Comment: Visual Studio is a devlopment environment. Perhaps you mean the. NET Regular Expression engine isn't happy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happy downloading..

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"^.*S\d\dE\d\d", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Ah now I get it.. You want to know why your regex doesn't work.. Well..

`(*[a-z][A-Z][0-9].)` this is wrong.

You can't have a quantifier pointing nothing. Here `*` matches greedily 0 to n times of nothing.. Error.

```
([a-z][A-Z][0-9].)
```

This means to match one letter from a-z followed by one letter from A-Z followed by one number from 0-9 followed by anything. So you are looking for aA1# or something. What you probably really meant to write was : `\w*` which matches 0 to n times of [a-zA-Z0-9_]

```
{*}
```

Also wrong.. Match the `{` as many times as possible followed by `}`? See above for what you really meant.

```
\\d\\d
```

Also wrong. You meant to match a digit but what you do actually search here is a `\` followed by the letter `d`.

Etc. I suggest you start reading some [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

;maybe a bit late, but this should work.

I have more that i can share, but this should be enough to get you started.

For this regex, the show should be in the format:
Show.Name.S01E02.Source.Quality.Etc-Group
Show Name - S01E02 - My Ep Name
Show.Name.S01.E03.My.Ep.Name
Show.Name.S01E02E03.Source.Quality.Etc-Group
Show Name - S01E02-03 - My Ep Name
Show.Name.S01.E02.E03

```
var filename = "";

string Standard = @"^((?<series_name>.+?)[. _-]+)?s(?<season_num>\d+)[. _-]*e(?<ep_num>\d+)(([. _-]*e|-)(?<extra_ep_num>(?!(1080|720)[pi])\d+))*[. _-]*((?<extra_info>.+?)((?<![. _-])-(?<release_group>[^-]+))?)?$";
```

For this regex, the show should be in the format:
Show.Name.1x01.etc
Show name - 1x02
ShowName S01E01

```
string Fov = @"^((?<series_name>.+?)[\[. _-]+)?(?<season_num>\d+)x(?<ep_num>\d+)(([. _-]*x|-)(?<extra_ep_num>(?!(1080|720)[pi])(?!(?<=x)264)\d+))*[\]. _-]*((?<extra_info>.+?)((?<![. _-])-(?<release_group>[^-]+))?)?$"

var regexStandard = new Regex('insert fov or standard here', RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match episode = regexStandard.Match(filename);

var Showname = episode.Groups["series_name"].Value;
var Season = episode.Groups["season_num"].Value;
var Episode = episode.Groups["ep_num"].Value;

Console.WriteLine(Showname + " " + Season + " " + Episode);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Doesn't work for 'tv.show.name.104.some.group.x264.mp4' or anything with 2 sets of numbers, like 1600 Penn (1600.penn.108.OTHER.mp4).

Comment: @Rob Do you have any regex standards for Movie file names?

Comment: string Numeric = @"^((?<series_name>.+?)[. _-]+)?(?<ep_num>\d+)(([. _-]*e|-)(?<extra_ep_num>(?!(1080|720)[pi])\d+))*[. _-]*((?<extra_info>.+?)((?<![. _-])-(?<release_group>[^-]+))?)?$";